# Flask error: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi']

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am making a simple Flask app on Raspberry pi, but I cannot include `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO` in python code. This is the output error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "rgbw.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "rgbw", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/rgbw/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/var/www/html/rgbw/rgbw.py", line 5, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'
```

I have installed GPIO inside the virtual environment, so I don't know why it doesn't want to work.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got `RPi.GPIO` installed? (You can check by running `pip freeze` in the virtual environment.) If not you can install it with: `pip install RPi.GPIO`

`import RPi.GPIO as GPIO`
is trying to import the function `GPIO` from the library `RPi.GPIO` which is not the same library as `GPIO`.

I hope this solves your problem, if not please add a copy of your code and `pip freeze` to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much. My mistake was that I was trying to install RPi.GPIO with `sudo apt-get -y install python3-rpi.gpio` (I found that on the internet). `pip install RPi.GPIO` solved my problem. I would upvote your post if I could!

Comment: bumping here for anyone running code on a Raspberry Pi in a venv environment. you'll have to install with `pip install RPi.GPIO` as @MatjažMeža says. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... I tried `pip install RPi.GPIO`, and it didn't solve my problem (working ony when running the python program from Geany, but not from the terminal).

`sudo apt-get -y install python3-rpi.gpio` solved the issue, making it possible to run my program from the terminal.